# Issues using highcharts node export server from ClojureScript - "0x03 error when performing chart generation"

Tags: javascript, node.js, highcharts

I have a clojurescript app on Node.js, and am attempting to use the highcharts export server as a Node.js module in order to generate charts for the purpose of PDF generation.

I have followed the example as seen under "Using as a Node.js Module" here: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server. This example uses the following javascript object as input data for the chart:

```
var exportSettings = {
type: 'png',
options: {
        title: {
            text: 'My Chart'
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]
        },
        series: [
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: [1, 3, 2, 4]
            },
            {
                type: 'line',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 2]
            }
        ]
    }
};
```

Replicating this example in clojurescript, defining the export settings as a clojurescript map and converting it back to a javascript object:

```
(def test-chart (clj->js {:type    "png"
                      :options {:title  {:text "My Chart"}
                                :xAxis  {:categories ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Mar", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"]}
                                :series [{:type "line"
                                          :data [1 3 2 4]}
                                         {:type "line"
                                          :data [5 3 4 2]}]}}))
```

Logging the test-chart object to console confirms it's identical to the javascript object used in the example:

```
{ type: 'png',  
  options: { title: { text: 'My Chart' },     
             xAxis: { categories: [Array] },     
             series: [{ type: 'line', data: [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ] },
                      { type: 'line', data: [ 5, 3, 4, 2 ] }] 
    } 
}
```

Further calling the required Highcharts functions to set up a phantom.js worker pool and generate the chart as seen in the example:

```
(doto Highcharts
(.initPool)
(.export test-chart (fn [err res]
                      (when err (println "****" err))))
(.killPool))
```

When calling export with the converted clojure map as input data, the error **"0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data"** is seen.

The documentation example does work in regular Node.JS, but when calling export from clojurescript using input data converted from a clojure map, the export fails with this input data error. As the converted object looks correct from console, and everything else should be identical just done through javascript interop, I am not sure what the issue could be here.

Is there something that would cause the exporter to be unable to parse the input data object if converted from a clojure map? Or could the issue be something else, and checking input data is a misleading error message?

Comment: Commas are optional in Clojure. They are added automatically by the clj->js conversion when converting to a JavaScript object.

Comment: Okay, I didn't know that : . Could you post what the series object looks like. What I am really after is seeing if numbers have been converted to strings or other things like that.

Comment: It's correct. 

    [ { type: 'line', data: [ 1, 3, 2, 4 ] },
      { type: 'line', data: [ 5, 3, 4, 2 ] } ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your ClojureScript code is not equivalent to the example code in the readme. In the example, `killPool` is called in the callback function passed into `export`. In your version, you call `killPool` immediately after calling export so chart generation likely does not have time to finish. I suspect this is causing the error.

The updated ClojureScript would look like this:

```
(doto Highcharts
  (.initPool)
  (.export test-chart (fn [err res]
                        (when err (println "****" err))
                        (.killPool Highcharts))))
```

Comment: Omg. you're completely correct of course. Over several hours of staring and changing minute details around I completely missed this. Calling killPool inside the callback fixes the issue, as you suspected.