# getting 0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data in Highchart

Tags: node.js, highcharts

1. i am using highchart export server for generate chart in NodeJs
2. but when i am generating many charts it gives error like **0x03 error when performing chart generation: please check your input data**
3. here is my code

   ```
   exports.generateAllCharts = (chartData, callback) => {

   highchartsExporter.initPool({
       maxWorkers: 100,
       initialWorkers: 40,
       workLimit: 100,
       queueSize: 40,
       timeoutThreshold: 600000
   });

   var allPromises = [];
   if(!chartData ||chartData.length === 0) {
       return callback({
           code: '4',
           msg: 'Please send chartdata'
       })
   }

   allPromises.push(exports.getStockChartImg(chartData[1]));
   allPromises.push(exports.priceChartVsPeersImg(chartData[2]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[3]));

   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[4]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[5]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[6]));

   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[13]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[14]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[15]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[16]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[18]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[19]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[7]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[17]));

   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[20]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[21]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[22]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[23]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[24]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[25]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[26]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[27]));

   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[33]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[34]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getGlobalOwnershipDistributionChartImg(chartData[35]));

   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[36]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[37]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[38]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[39]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[40]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[41]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[42]));
   allPromises.push(exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[43]));


   Promise.all(allPromises)
   .then(data => {
       highchartsExporter.killPool();
       return  callback({
           code: '0',
           custImg: {
               pc1: data[0].data,
               pc2: data[1].data,
               pc3: data[2].data,
               pc4: data[3].data,
               pc5: data[4].data,
               pc6: data[5].data,
               pc7: data[6].data,
               pc8: data[7].data,
               pc9: data[8].data,
               pc10: data[9].data,
               pc11: data[10].data,
               pc12: data[11].data,
               pc13: data[12].data,
               pc14: data[13].data,
               pc17: data[14].data,
               pc18: data[15].data,
               pc19: data[16].data,
               pc20: data[17].data,
               pc21: data[18].data,
               pc22: data[19].data,
               pc23: data[20].data,
               pc24: data[21].data,
               pc27: data[22].data,
               pc28: data[23].data,
               pc29: data[24].data,
               pc30: data[25].data,
               pc31: data[26].data,
               pc32: data[27].data,
               pc33: data[28].data,
               pc34: data[29].data,
               pc35: data[30].data,
               pc36: data[31].data,
               pc37: data[32].data,
           }
       })
   })
   .catch(err => callback({
       code: '5',
       msg: 'Error generating charts',
       err,
   }))
   }

     exports.getPieChartImg = (seriesData, xOrLength) => {
       var chartOpts = {
           colors: ['#7380D4', '#749FD4', '#74BFD4', '#74D4B6', '#99EBA8', '#FEE08B', '#FDAE61', '#F07346', '#E65433', '#C92D22'],
           chart: {
               plotBackgroundColor: null,
               plotBorderWidth: null,
               plotShadow: false,
               renderTo: 'container',
               style: {
                   fontSize: '20px',
                   background: '#fffdcc'
               },
               width:650,
           },
           credits: {
               enabled: false
           },
           title: {
               text: null,
           },
           tooltip: {
               pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.percentage:.1f}%'
           },
           legend: {
               itemStyle: {
                   font: 'sans-serif',
                   fontWeight: 'bold',
                   fontSize: '13px'
               },
               useHTML: true,
               layout: 'vertical',
               align: 'right',
               verticalAlign: 'middle',
               labelFormatter: ()=> {
                   if (this.name[xOrLength] > 9) {

                       var words = this.name.split(/[\s]+/);
                       var numWordsPerLine = 1;
                       var str = [];

                       for (var word in words) {
                           if (parseInt(word) > 0 && parseInt(word) % numWordsPerLine == 0)
                               str.push('<br>');

                           str.push(words[word]);
                       }

                       var label = str.join(' ');

                       // Make legend text bold and red if most recent value is less than prior
                       if (this.name[1] > this.name[2]) {
                           return '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + label + '</span>';
                       } else {
                           return label;
                       }
                   } else {
                       return this.name;
                   }
               }
           },
           plotOptions: {
               pie: {
                   size: '85%',
                   allowPointSelect: true,
                   cursor: 'pointer',
                   showInLegend: true,
                   dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true,
                       allowOverlap: false,
                       distance: 10,
                       formatter: ()=> {
                           return undefined;
                           // if (parseFloat(this.percentage.toFixed(2)) > 0.35) {
                           //     return '' + parseFloat(this.percentage).toFixed(2) + '%';
                           // }
                       },
                       padding: 5,
                       style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', /*lineHeight: '18px',*/ fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: '18px' }
                   }
               },
               series: {
                   stacking: 'normal',
                   dataLabels: {
                       enabled: true,
                       color: '#6f6f6f',
                       style: { fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif', /*lineHeight: '18px',*/ fontWeight: 'normal', fontSize: '18px' },
                       format:'{point.percentage:.2f}' 
                   },
                   pointWidth: 30,
                   cursor: 'pointer'
               }
           },
           series: [{
               name: "Value",
               type: 'pie',
               data: seriesData
           }],
           navigation: {
               buttonOptions: {
                   enabled: false
               }
           },
       };

       var exportSettings = generateExportSettings(chartOpts, 'Stock');
       return generateBase64Chart(exportSettings, 3)
   }
   function generateExportSettings(chartOpts, constr) {
       return {
           // b64: true,
           instr: JSON.stringify(chartOpts),
           noDownload: true,
           constr,
           globalOptions: {
               colors: ['#7380D4', '#749FD4', '#74BFD4', '#74D4B6', '#99EBA8', '#FEE08B', '#FDAE61', '#F07346', '#E65433', '#C92D22'],
               lang: {
                   thousandsSep: ','
               }
           },
           scale: 2,
           styledMode: false,
           type: "image/png",
           width: false,
       };
   }

   function generateBase64Chart(exportSettings, number) {
       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
           //Perform an export
           highchartsExporter.export(exportSettings, function (err, res) {
               //The export result is now in res.
               //If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
               //If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).
               if(err) {
                   Logger.error("IN ERROR: ", number);
                   Logger.error("ERROR: ", err);
                   return reject({
                       code: '1',
                       err,
                       msg: 'Error in stock chart',
                       exportSettings
                   })
               }
               return resolve({
                   code: '0',
                   msg: 'success',
                   data: 'data:image/png;base64,' + res.data,
               })
               //Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
               // highchartsExporter.killPool();
               // process.exit(1);
           });
       })
   }
   ```

> **i am generating all charts at a time, so how can i solve this problem.**

Comment: See the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51878045/issues-using-highcharts-node-export-server-from-clojurescript-0x03-error-when

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun i do the same you can see in my code **(i call killPool method)**, but still getting error

Comment: @Chaudhary Could you provide all required code in order to run the above node module? What do all the custom functions (getStockChartImg, priceChartVsPeersImg, getPieChartImg and getGlobalOwnershipDistributionChartImg) do? Please, provide a simplified example. Also, see this: https://github.com/highcharts/node-export-server/blob/master/tests/module/promises.js example in the node export server repository to see promise-based code that works and export charts correctly.

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun i have edited my question, i am generating chart in all the other functions & **i think there was some memory leakage problem, so how can i release memory after chart generation?**

Comment: @Chaudhary try running your file with the following command ``node --expose-gc charts.js``

Comment: @AbdulrahmanFalyoun i am using PM2 for start node server, **pm2 start server.js**, so how can i use your command with this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your code a little bit (and used the getPieChartImg as it is the only one available) and tried to export a big number of charts (35 in this case). I don't encounter the 0x03-error. Here is the modified code:

(test.js)

```
const exporter = require('./promise-based.js');

let numberOfCharts = 35;
let chartsData = [];

for (let i = 0; i < numberOfCharts; i++) {
    chartsData.push([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]);
}

exporter.generateAllCharts(chartsData, results => {
    if (results.code === '0') {
        console.log('All charts exported!');
        console.log(results);
    } else {
        console.log('Error #' + results.code + ': ' + results.msg);
        if (results.err) {
            console.log(results.err);
        }
    }
    process.exit();
});
```

(promise-based.js)

```
const highchartsExporter = require('highcharts-export-server');

let promiseId = 0;

exports.generateAllCharts = (chartData, callback) => {
    let allPromises = [];
    let chartsLen = chartData.length;

    highchartsExporter.logLevel(4);
    highchartsExporter.initPool({
        maxWorkers: 100,
        initialWorkers: 50,
        workLimit: 100,
        queueSize: 50,
        timeoutThreshold: 10000
    });

    if (!chartData || !chartsLen) {
        highchartsExporter.killPool();

        return callback({
            code: '4',
            msg: 'Please send chartdata'
        });
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < chartsLen; i++) {
        allPromises.push(
            new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                exports.getPieChartImg(chartData[i], false, results => {
                    if (results.code !== '0') {
                        return reject(results);
                    }

                    return resolve(results);
                });
            })
        );
    }

    Promise.all(allPromises)
        .then(data => {
            highchartsExporter.killPool();

            let imagesObject = {
                code: '0',
                custImg: {}
            };

            data.forEach((image, index) => {
                imagesObject.custImg['pc' + (index + 1)] = image.data;
                imagesObject.custImg.promiseId = image.promiseId;
            });

            return callback(imagesObject);
        })
        .catch(err => callback({
            code: '5',
            msg: 'Error generating charts',
            err
        }));
};

exports.getPieChartImg = (seriesData, xOrLength, cb) => {
    let chartOpts = {
        colors: ['#7380D4', '#749FD4', '#74BFD4', '#74D4B6', '#99EBA8', '#FEE08B', '#FDAE61', '#F07346', '#E65433', '#C92D22'],
        chart: {
            plotBackgroundColor: null,
            plotBorderWidth: null,
            plotShadow: false,
            renderTo: 'container',
            style: {
                fontSize: '20px',
                background: '#fffdcc'
            },
            width: 650,
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        },
        title: {
            text: null,
        },
        tooltip: {
            pointFormat: '{series.name}: {point.percentage:.1f}%'
        },
        legend: {
            itemStyle: {
                font: 'sans-serif',
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '13px'
            },
            useHTML: true,
            layout: 'vertical',
            align: 'right',
            verticalAlign: 'middle',
            labelFormatter: () => {
                if (this.name[xOrLength] > 9) {
                    let words = this.name.split(/[\s]+/);
                    let numWordsPerLine = 1;
                    let str = [];

                    for (let word in words) {
                        if (parseInt(word) > 0 && parseInt(word) % numWordsPerLine == 0)
                            str.push('<br>');

                        str.push(words[word]);
                    }

                    let label = str.join(' ');

                    // Make legend text bold and red if most recent value is less than prior
                    if (this.name[1] > this.name[2]) {
                        return '<span style="font-weight:bold">' + label + '</span>';
                    } else {
                        return label;
                    }
                } else {
                    return this.name;
                }
            }
        },
        plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                size: '85%',
                allowPointSelect: true,
                cursor: 'pointer',
                showInLegend: true,
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    allowOverlap: false,
                    distance: 10,
                    formatter: () => {
                        return undefined;
                        // if (parseFloat(this.percentage.toFixed(2)) > 0.35) {
                        //     return '' + parseFloat(this.percentage).toFixed(2) + '%';
                        // }
                    },
                    padding: 5,
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif',
                        // lineHeight: '18px',
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        fontSize: '18px'
                    }
                }
            },
            series: {
                stacking: 'normal',
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    color: '#6f6f6f',
                    style: {
                        fontFamily: '\'Lato\', sans-serif',
                        // lineHeight: '18px',
                        fontWeight: 'normal',
                        fontSize: '18px'
                    },
                    format: '{point.percentage:.2f}'
                },
                pointWidth: 30,
                cursor: 'pointer'
            }
        },
        series: [{
            name: "Value",
            type: 'pie',
            data: seriesData
        }],
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                enabled: false
            }
        },
    };

    let exportSettings = generateExportSettings(chartOpts, 'Stock');
    return generateBase64Chart(exportSettings, 3, cb);
};

function generateExportSettings(chartOpts, constr) {
    return {
        type: 'png',
        constr,
        b64: true,
        // async: false,
        noDownload: true,
        scale: 2,
        options: chartOpts,
        globalOptions: {
            colors: ['#7380D4', '#749FD4', '#74BFD4', '#74D4B6', '#99EBA8', '#FEE08B', '#FDAE61', '#F07346', '#E65433', '#C92D22'],
            lang: {
                thousandsSep: ','
            }
        }
    };
}

function generateBase64Chart(exportSettings, number, cb) {
    // Perform an export
    highchartsExporter.export(exportSettings, function(err, res) {
        // The export result is now in res.
        // If the output is not PDF or SVG, it will be base64 encoded (res.data).
        // If the output is a PDF or SVG, it will contain a filename (res.filename).

        if (err) {
            return cb({
                code: '1',
                msg: 'Error in stock chart',
                err,
                exportSettings
            });
        }

        promiseId++;
        return cb({
            code: '0',
            msg: 'Success',
            promiseId: promiseId,
            data: 'data:image/png;base64,' + res.data,
        });
        // Kill the pool when we're done with it, and exit the application
        // highchartsExporter.killPool();
        // process.exit(1);
    });
}
```